# C - How to concatenate Strings without string.h and with dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, concatenation

I have to do an exercise and I have this structure given:

```
typedef struct {
    char *str;
    unsigned int len;
} String;
```

My Task is to write a String Concat which concats `"Kartoffel"` and `"puffer"` to `"Kartoffelpuffer"` (potato fritter).

```
String concat(String l, String r)
```

Both Strings `l` and `r` should not be changed after running the function.
First I created the two Strings in the main:

```
String1 *l = malloc(sizeof(String1));
String1 *r = malloc(sizeof(String1));
(*l).str = malloc(sizeof("Kartoffel"));
(*r).str = malloc(sizeof("puffer"));
(*l).str = "Kartoffel";
(*r).str = "puffer";
(*l).len = 9;
(*r).len = 6;
```

Then I wrote the concat function:

```
String1 concat(String1 l, String1 r) {
    unsigned int i = 0;
    String1 *newStr = malloc(sizeof(String1));
    /* +1 for '\0' at the end */
    newStr->str = malloc(l.len + r.len + 1);
    newStr->str = l.str;
    /* The following line is not working */
    newStr->str[l.len] = *r.str;
    newStr->len = l.len + r.len;
    return *newStr;
}
```

What Im trying to do is working with pointer arithmetic.
When there is a pointer which points to the beginning of a storage area like `char *str`, it should be possible to move the pointer with `a[b]` or `*((a) + (b))` right? When I run the code I get Segmentation fault (I hope its the right translation. Original: `"Speicherzugriffsfehler"`).
If someone could give me a hint I would be thankful. PS: Sorry for my English.

Comment: So I also need to write a function which copies from one storage area to another?

Comment: `return *newStr;` leaks memory, too.

Answer (score 2):

First, `(*l).str = "Kartoffel";` makes `(*l).str` point to the `"Kartoffel"` string literal, meaning that the original memory allocated to `(*l).str` with `malloc()` is lost. Same for `(*r).str = "puffer";`. One of the things you can do to avoid this is copy the string into the allocated buffer by looping over the characters in a for loop (since you can't use `string.h`).

Then, in your `concat()` function, you do the same thing. You allocate the memory for `newStr->str` with `malloc()` (properly allocating an extra `char` for the null-terminator), but on the next line you re-assign that pointer to point to `l.str`, which is still pointing to the string literal. Then, with `newStr->str[l.len] = *r.str;` you are attempting to modify the string literal, which in C is undefined behavior.

The way to fix this could be, again, to copy the two strings into the buffer allocated with `newStr->str = malloc(l.len+r.len+1);`.

Answer (score 1):

After allocating memeory to `newStr` and `newStr->str`
Two pointers could be used. `char *to, *from;`
Set the pointers with `to = newStr->str;` and `from = l.str;`
copy the characters with `*to = *from;`
Advance the pointers with `to++;` and `from++;`
Repeat until `*from == 0`
Set `from` with `from = r.str;`
`to` does not need to be reset as it is correctly positioned at the end of `newStr->str`.
Repeat the copy of characters.
Repeat advancing the pointers.
Set a terminating 0 with `*to = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your help!
I wrote another method to copy the string as you guys said.

```
char * copyStr (char * dest,char * src){
    unsigned int index;
    for (index = 0; src[index] != '\0'; index++) {
            dest[index] = src[index];
    }
    dest[index] = '\0';
    return dest;
}
```

And I edited my concat like that:

```
String1 concat (String1 l, String1 r){
    String1 *newStr = malloc(sizeof(String1));
    newStr->str = malloc(l.len+r.len+1);
    copyStr(newStr->str,l.str);
    copyStr((newStr->str+l.len),r.str);
    newStr->len = l.len+r.len;
    return *newStr;
}
```

with `newStr->str+l.len` the pointer will be moved. If l.len is 9, the pointer will point to the 10th byte, which is the end of the first string l. So the the String r will be copied in the memory storage behind the first string l.

Comment: Looks good, except that `return *newStr;` leaks memory: `newStr` is copied to the returned object, but then information about the original pointer is lost. It is better to return a `String1*` instead, so you can free the object when you're done with it.